# Haskell 99 questions #8: Can't understand foldr

Tags: haskell

I'm doing exercise of Haskell [99 questions](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10).

> ## Problem 8
>
> Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements.
>
> If a list contains repeated elements they should be replaced with a
>   single copy of the element. The order of the elements should not be
>   changed.
>
> Example in Haskell:
>
> ```
>  > compress "aaaabccaadeeee" 
>
>  "abcade"
> ```

I can't understand this solution:

```
compress xs = foldr f (const []) xs Nothing
  where
    f x r a@(Just q) | x == q = r a
    f x r _ = x : r (Just x)
```

`foldr` takes three parameters. The first parameter is a function `(a -> b -> b)`. The second is initial accumulator and the third is a list.

Is `(const [])` the second parameter passed to `foldr`?

The function `f :: Eq a => a -> (Maybe a -> [a]) -> Maybe a -> [a]` takes three parameters, doesn't match what's expected by `foldr`. What values are passed in?

The last `Nothing` is for what?

Comment: I too am having trouble wrapping my head around this one. My guess is that `foldr` is building and returning a function, and `Nothing` is then the input to that function...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Sounds right. The type signature of `f` helps: `f :: Eq a => a -> (Maybe a -> [a]) -> (Maybe a -> [a])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jubobs points out, `f` has the signature `f :: Eq a => a -> (Maybe a -> [a]) -> (Maybe a -> [a])` In the context of `foldr`'s signature, that means `a` is `a`, and `b` is `(Maybe a -> [a])`. So the `foldr` indeed builds a complicated function.

Let's look at the list `"aab"`, a very simple input. The fold expands to

```
(f 'a' (f 'a' (f 'b' (const []))))
```

Passing `Nothing` to that construct, you can start expanding it. The outermost call then has

```
x = 'a'
r = <the inner stuff>
a@(Just q) fails to match Nothing
_ matches Nothing
```

so its result is `'a' : r (Just 'a')`. Substituting `r` we get:

```
'a' : f 'a' (f 'b' (const [])) (Just 'a')
```

The new outermost call to `f` then has

```
x = 'a'
r = (f 'b' (const []))
a@(Just q) matches Just 'a'
guard 'a' == 'a' is true
```

So the `r a` branch is taken, i.e. it just forwards to the next in chain. The result of the function is `r (Just 'a')`, and the result of the entire expression is currently `'a' : r (Just 'a')`. Substitute `r` again:

```
'a' : f 'b' (const []) (Just 'a')
```

The new parameters to `f`:

```
x = 'b'
r = const []
a@(Just q) matches Just 'a'
guard 'b' == 'a' is false
_ matches Just 'a'
```

We take the second option again, because the guard failed. The guard basically says, "if the previous character (`q`, `a` is `Nothing` if there was no previous character) is the same as the current (`x`), don't put it in the output, otherwise do".

So the function result is `'b' : const [] (Just 'b')`, and the full expression result as we currently see it is `'a' : 'b' : const [] (Just 'b')`.

The `const` function ignores its second argument and returns the first. It looks like this:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const x _ = x
```

In the call in our expression, the arguments match like this:

```
x = []
_ = Just 'b'
```

The result therefore is `[]`. The entire expression is now `'a' : 'b' : []`, or in string syntax, `"ab"`. The duplicate `'a'` has been removed.

You can play this game on paper for a longer expression if you want.

The solution basically uses `foldr` to build a function that uses continuation passing style so it can carry state along. It's a funky technique. A more intuitive way of carrying state through a fold would be to make the fold result a tuple of the actual accumulator and the state you want to carry, then extract the proper result at the end. For your problem, this could look like this:

```
compress s = fst $ foldr f ([], Nothing) s
  where
    f cur (acc, (Just prev)) | cur == prev = (acc, (Just prev))
    f cur (acc, _) = (cur : acc, Just cur)
```

This should work just as well. Note, however, that this **reverses** the order the state is carried, i.e. it walks through the string backwards. I'm not sure what the performance or laziness of one vs the other is. I think the CPS solution is more lazy, but I am not sure.

Comment: Very clear explanation. In the last intuitive solution, shall it be `compress s = fst $ foldr f ([], Nothing) s`?

Comment: @aleung Yes, it should. Edited.

Answer (score 6):

You say

> `foldr` takes three parameters

This is misleading. The type of `foldr` is

```
(a -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r
```

where `r` is a type variable that can be instantiated by any type, including a function type. This is what is happening here, and the hint is indeed given by the fact that the second argument passed to `foldr` (which should match `r`) is `const []`.

The type at that `foldr` is used here is the following:

```
foldr :: Eq a => (a -> (Maybe a -> [a]) -> Maybe a -> [a]) -> (Maybe a -> [a]) -> [a] -> Maybe a -> [a]
foldr ::         (a -> r                -> r             ) -> r                -> [a] -> r
```

Once you know that `r` is instantiated to `Maybe a -> [a]`, it becomes clear that `f` effectively takes three arguments here, and `foldr` takes four.

A much simpler example of the same phenomenon is this:

```
id id 2
```

Here, `id` appears to have two arguments. The outer `id` is used at a function type, the inner `id` is used with an `Integer` argument.